# Can I run cloud optimized version of asp.net-vnext as normal asp.net project on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

Can I run cloud optimized version of asp.net-vnext as normal asp.net project on IIS.I know that we have option to select cloud optimized or full .net package.If I start development on cloud optimized ,is it possible deploy on iis as normal asp.net web project or it specific for azure?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can run the application on IIS.

First, run `kpm pack --runtime <CoreCLR package name>` (example of package name: `KRE-CoreCLR-amd64.1.0.0-beta2`) on your application. That will produce a folder with all your application needs (app files, dependencies and the runtime).

Then, copy that folder to where your application will live and point IIS to it.

Done :)

Later edit: make sure you pack the runtime that matches the architecture (64 bit IIS -> 64 bit CoreCLR or 32 bit IIS -> 32 bit CoreCLR). Otherwise it will not work.